# Is proving for $F(x+ct)$ WLOG instead of $F(x+t)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to show that $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ is a solution to 1D wave eq.

However, since the wave eq. has the constant $c^2$:

$$u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx}=0$$

then I have difficulties in seeing how $u_{tt}$, $u_{xx}$ cancel each other, when $u_{xx}$ has the $c^2$ term, which $u(x,t)$ doesn't carry.

Comment: In your case $c=1$.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan I wasn't given that $u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)$ has $c=1$. Can I interpret it as having $c=1$?

Comment: yes. $c$ is a varying constant.

Comment: $c$ depends on the tension and density.

Comment: Please see the derivation.

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m256/wave.pdf

Comment: This may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$
u(x,t)=F(x+t)+G(x-t)
$$
satisfies the equation
$$
u_{tt}=u_{xx}
$$
and NOT
$$
u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}
$$

Comment: So does it satisfy the 1D wave equation then?

Comment: Yes, but with $c=1$.